swiper-slide-next is working but not loading images when i click on it and swiper-slide-prev is working and loading images Same with pagination
I have been working on this for few days now and i am gonna need your helpenter image description here
My jsx file
import React from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "./ExploreSection.css";
import { Link, replace } from "react-router-dom";



import Australiaicon from "../../../assests/Australia.jpg";
import USAicon from "../../../assests/usa.jpg";
import Germanyicon from "../../../assests/Germany.jpg";
import Canadaicon from "../../../assests/Canada.jpg";
import UKicon from "../../../assests/uk.jpg";
import Latviaicon from "../../../assests/LatviaExplore.jpg";
import Lithuaniaicon from "../../../assests/LithuaniaExplore.jpg";
import Franceicon from "../../../assests/FranceExplore.jpg";
import Swedenicon from "../../../assests/SwedenExplore.jpg";
import Finlandicon from "../../../assests/FinlandExplore.jpg";
import Irelandicon from "../../../assests/IrelandExplore.jpg";
import Maltaicon from "../../../assests/MaltaExplore.jpg";
import Sloveniaicon from "../../../assests/SloveniaExplore.jpg";
import Hungaryicon from "../../../assests/HungaryExplore.jpg";
import Austriaicon from "../../../assests/AustriaExplore.jpg";

import { Keyboard, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper/modules";

const ExploreSection = () => {
  const cards = [
    { imgSrc: USAicon, name: "USA" },
    { imgSrc: Germanyicon, name: "Germany" },
    { imgSrc: UKicon, name: "United Kingdom" },
    { imgSrc: Australiaicon, name: "Australia" },
    { imgSrc: Canadaicon, name: "Canada" },
    { imgSrc: Latviaicon, name: "Latvia" },
    { imgSrc: Lithuaniaicon, name: "Lithuania" },
    { imgSrc: Swedenicon, name: "Sweden" },
    { imgSrc: Franceicon, name: "France" },
    { imgSrc: Finlandicon, name: "Finland" },
    { imgSrc: Irelandicon, name: "Ireland" },
    { imgSrc: Maltaicon, name: "Malta" },
    { imgSrc: Sloveniaicon, name: "Slovenia" },
    { imgSrc: Austriaicon, name: "Austria" },
    { imgSrc: Hungaryicon, name: "Hungary" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className="explore-heading">
        <h1>Explore the Best of the World</h1>
      </div>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={4}
        preloadImages={true}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        observer={true}
        observeParents={true}
        breakpoints={{
          500: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 20,
          },
          700: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
          },
          1000: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
          },
          1024: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          },
        }}
        keyboard={{
          enabled: true,
        }}
        navigation={true}
        modules={[Keyboard, Pagination, Navigation]}
        loop={true}
        // loopFillGroupWithBlank={true}
        // resistance={true}
        resistanceRatio={1}
        className="mySwiper1"
      >
        {cards.map((card, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slide-1" key={index}>
            <a href={`/${card.name.replace(/\s+/g, '')}Uni`}>
              <img src={card.imgSrc} alt={card.name} />
              <h3 className="card1">{card.name}</h3>
            </a>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
};

export default ExploreSection;


And my css
.explore-heading h1 {
  margin: 2%;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #0C5448;
  padding-bottom:2%;
}

.swiper-wrapper{
  margin-left: 0;
}

.mySwiper1 {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
.swiper-slide-1 {
  text-align: center;
  height:100%;
  margin-bottom:4vw;
  margin-right:0px;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
  
   
  .swiper-slide-1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .swiper-slide-1  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background: rgb(12,84,72);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(12,84,72,1) 13%, rgba(26,182,156,1) 64%);
  }

  .swiper-slide-1 h3{
    display: block;
    color:#F3AE27;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    padding:5%;
  }

  .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next{
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0% 3%;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    /* border: 2px solid #0C5448; */
    border-radius: 150%;
    background-color: #F3AE27;
  }
  .swiper-button-prev::after, .swiper-button-next::after{
    font-size: 30px;
  }


@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {

  .swiper-slide-1 a{
    width: 95%;   
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
  }

  .swiper-slide-1 img {
    width:100%;
    height: 42vh;
    object-fit: cover;
  } 
  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    
  .explore-heading h1{
    font-size: 2rem;
 }

  .swiper-wrapper{
    margin: 0;
  }

  .swiper-slide-1 {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto; /* Adjust this if necessary */
    min-width: 300px; /* Allow slides to resize properly */
  } 

  .swiper-slide-1 a{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 400px; /* Or some other max-width */
    height: auto;
  }

 .swiper-slide-1 img {
   width:100%;
   height: 42vh;
   object-fit: cover;
 } 

 .swiper-slide-1 h3{
  display: block;
  color:#F3AE27;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding:5%;
 }

  .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next{
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0% 5%;
    size: 50px;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }

  .swiper-pagination{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px){
 
  .swiper-slide-1 a{
    width: 100%;   
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
  }

  .swiper-slide-1 img {
    width:100%;
    height: 41vh;
    object-fit: cover;
  } 

  .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next{
    margin: 0% 3%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    
  }
  .swiper-button-prev::after, .swiper-button-next::after{
    font-size: 20px;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {

  .explore-heading h1{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .swiper-slide-1 a{
    width: 90%;   
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
  }

  .swiper-slide-1{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .swiper-slide-1 img {
    width:100%;
    height: 50vh;
    object-fit: cover;
  } 

  .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next{
    margin: 0% 3%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    
  }
  .swiper-button-prev::after, .swiper-button-next::after{
    font-size: 20px;
  }

}

I tried setting loop to flase // this is not working
Have imported the latests version of swiper // so thats not it as well
preloadImages is set true to avoid lazy loading // didn't help
Have checked the images if the paths are right // left swiper and pagination is working just fine and loading everything properly so it's not image imports
Right now I want the right swiper and right-pagination bottom bullets to working
